# Should this be a GET or a PATCH request?

Tags: rest, http

if i do a request to get some data from a database without sending any updates, however i'm marking the record in the database to say the data has been fetched, does that make it a PATCH request or a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, it is still a `GET`.

RFC 7231 defines [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only....

> This definition of safe methods does not prevent an implementation
> from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not
> entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe
> method.  What is important, however, is that the client did not
> request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for
> it.  For example, most servers append request information to access
> log files at the completion of every response, regardless of the
> method, and that is considered safe even though the log storage might
> become full and crash the server.  Likewise, a safe request initiated
> by selecting an advertisement on the Web will often have the side
> effect of charging an advertising account.

So if the client is trying to retrieve a current representation of the resource,
the fact that your implementation happens to do a bit of bookkeeping on the side doesn't change the semantics of the request.

Part of the point of an HTTP front end is that clients are completely insulated from the underlying implementation details of the server -- everything looks like a dumb web site from the outside.

Comment: I should have probably refreshed the page before posting :/ just a couple of minutes late ...

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) is rather clear on that if you read through the definition of `safe`:

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.  Likewise, reasonable use of a safe method is not expected to cause any harm, loss of property, or unusual burden on the origin server.
>
> This definition of safe methods **does not prevent an implementation from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe method.  What is important, however, is that the client did not request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for it.**  For example, most servers append request information to access log files at the completion of every response, regardless of the method, and that is considered safe even though the log storage might become full and crash the server.  Likewise, a safe request initiated by selecting an advertisement on the Web will often have the side effect of charging an advertising account.
>
> ...

So a state change through a `GET` triggered download is fine as long as the client is not aware of that state change.

In certain situations though, exposing a state change via `GET` may be risky. Just think of a crawler that invokes a couple of URIs that order some Pizza or the like. According to the spec this is fine and the crawler must not made accountable for that order. This is simply telling you that it was your fault.

With that being said, you can always use `POST` if you feel uncomfortable with certain HTTP operations as `POST` literally allows you to process the request according to the resources own semantics.

Which leads me to the next point of re-thinking your design. Returning some document that includes it own state is somehow strange in my opinion. Usually such information is meta-data about a document but not the resource itself. Here you could either use HTTP headers to communicate such information to the client or design the state of that resource as yet a further resource you can hint a client about providing it a link to look it up if it is interested.

Anyway, while not elegant performing a state change on retrieving a resource via `GET`  is not forbidden. I would though invest a couple more thoughts on whether you want to include the state within the resource itself or expose it via its own resource.