# HTTP GET for 'background' job creation and acquiring

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I'm designing API for jobs scheduler. There is one scheduler with some set of resources and DB tables for them. Also there are multiple 'workers' that request 'jobs' from scheduler. Worker can't create job it must only request it. Job must be calculated on the server side. Also job is a dynamic entity and calculated using multiple DB tables and time. There is no 'job' table.

In general this system is very similar to task queue. But without queue. I need a method for worker to request next task. That task should be calculated and assigned for this agent.

Is it OK to use `GET` verb to retrieve and 'lock' job for the specific worker?
In terms of resources this query does not modify anything. Only internal DB state is updated. For client it looks like fetching records one by one. It doesn't know about internal modifications.

In pure REST style I probably should define a job table and CRUD api for it. Then I would need to create some auxilary service to `POST` jobs to that table. Then each agent would list jobs using `GET` and then lock it using PATCH. That approach requires multiple potential retries due to race-conditions. (Job can be already locked by another agent). Also it looks a little bit complicated if I need to assign job to specific agent based on server side logic. In that case I need to implement some check logic on client side to iterate through jobs based on different responces.

This approach looks complicated.

Comment: This basically boils down to the same answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674054/should-this-be-a-get-or-a-patch-request/56675176#56675176).

Comment: Thank you, this is an answer for me. As I understood it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OK to use GET verb to retrieve and 'lock' job for the specific worker?

Maybe?  But probably not.

The important thing to understand about `GET` is that it is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> The purpose of distinguishing between safe and unsafe methods is to
> allow automated retrieval processes (spiders) and cache performance
> optimization (pre-fetching) to work without fear of causing harm.  In
> addition, it allows a user agent to apply appropriate constraints on
> the automated use of unsafe methods when processing potentially
> untrusted content.

If aggressive cache performance optimization would make a mess in your system, then `GET` is not the http method you want triggering that behavior.

If you were designing your client interactions around resources, then you would probably have something like a list of jobs assigned to a worker.  Reading the current representation of that resource doesn't require that a server change it, so `GET` is completely appropriate.  And of course the server could update that resource for its own reasons at any time.

Requests to modify that resource should not be safe.  For instance, if the client is going to signal that some job was completed, that should be done via an unsafe method (POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/...)

> I don't have such resource. It's an ephymeric resource which is spread across the tables. There is no DB table for that and there is no ID column to update that job. That's another question why I don't have such table but it's current requirement and limitation.

Fair enough, though the main lesson still stands.

Another way of thinking about it is to think about failure.  The [network is unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing).  In a distributed environment, the client cannot distinguish a lost request from a lost response.  All it knows is that it didn't receive an acknowledgement for the request.

When you use `GET`, you are implicitly telling the client that it is safe (there's that word again) to resend the request.  Not only that, but you are also implicitly telling any intermediate components that it is safe to repeat the request.

If there are no adverse effects to handling multiple copies of the same request, the `GET` is fine.  But if processing multiple copies of the same request is expensive, then you should probably be using `POST` instead.

It's not *required* that the `GET` handler be safe -- the standard only describes the semantics of the messages; it doesn't constraint the implementation at all.  But any [loss of property](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) incurred is properly understood to be the responsibility of the server.

Comment: > then you would probably have something like a list of jobs assigned to a worker

That's the main reason of the question. I don't have such resource. It's an ephymeric resource which is spread accross the tables. There is no DB table for that and there is no ID column to update that job. That's another question why I don't have such table but it's current requirement and limitation.

Comment: Understood; see if the update helps clarify things.